# Cumulative average of an average

Tags: average

I am trying to do a calculation for a stochastic oscillator on a series of stock prices in a database (SQL Server 2014). The calculation I am trying to do is as follows:

- Work out the lowest low for the last 14 periods (including the current one)
- Calculate the raw value by: 100 * (CurrentClose-LowestLow) / (CurrentHigh-LowestLow)
- Return field k as the average of the raw value for the last 3 periods (including the current one)
- Return field d as the average of field k for the last 3 periods (including the current one)

Here is some test data:

```
High    Lowest  Close   rawK        K           D
7.39    7.251   7.33    56.83453237     
7.38    7.251   7.282   24.03100775     
7.432   7.251   7.3     27.0718232  35.97912111 
7.38    7.203   7.38    100         50.36761032 
7.35    7.203   7.214   7.482993197 44.85160547 43.73277897
7.349   7.203   7.349   100         69.16099773 54.79340451
7.399   7.203   7.3     49.48979592 52.32426304 55.44562208
7.501   7.203   7.501   100         83.16326531 68.21617536
7.549   7.203   7.49    82.94797688 77.4792576  70.98892865
7.649   7.203   7.649   100         94.31599229 84.98617173
7.609   7.203   7.609   100         94.31599229 88.70374739
7.504   7.203   7.473   89.70099668 96.56699889 95.06632783
7.688   7.203   7.483   57.73195876 82.47765181 91.12021433
7.558   7.203   7.558   100         82.47765181 87.17410084
```

Because I am trying to calculate this on a database table it would be great if I could calculate the moving average k and the moving average of the moving average d with just one pass of the data.

I'm guessing I can calculate k as a cumulative average, but how do I calculate a cumulative average of a cumulative average with just the raw data?

Comment: I don't think this is the right forum for this question. Consider http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I understand - the question isn't database related, it's more related to working out if I can calculate the cumulative average and the average of a cumulative average on a cumulative basis rather than constantly iterating over the whole dataset